# Poisson regression on binary outcomes with `glmnet`?

Tags: poisson-regression, glmnet, robust-standard-error

Because my event is not particularly rare, I am more interested in risk ratios than odds ratios for my current generalized linear modeling problem, which calls for regularized regression. I'm doing regularized regression with `glmnet`. I know that you can obtain risk ratio effects instead of odds ratio effects by fitting a Poisson regression with robust error variance, which is preferred because not using robust error variance inflates your confidence intervals. Well `glmnet` does not provide confidence intervals, so I'm only looking at point estimates. My question is whether I could fit a Poisson regression to binary data using `glmnet` without having coefficients being shrunken to zero that shouldn't because of the way `glmnet` treats error variance.